# Nginx Least Connection Load Balancing

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm reading about **Least Connection** (least outstanding requests) algorithm in Nginx ([from here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)) but I have question about it. I know that this algorithm sends the request to server with least connections. suppose we have two server A and B. A has 1 connection and B has 2. now Nginx server received 10 requests simultaneously. how Nginx distribute these requests? does it forward all requests to A?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is single-threaded! The main event loop waits for the OS to signal. so the OS determines the order of processing requests.